# Why does append() and += give different results when I want to add a dictionary into a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to append a dictionary `germany` into a list `travel_log`.

```
travel_log = [
{
  "country": "France",
  "visits": 12,
  "cities": ["Paris", "Lille", "Dijon"]
}]
germany = {
  "country": "Germany",
  "visits": 5,
  "cities": ["Berlin", "Hamburg", "Stuttgart"]
}
```

When I use `travel_log += germany`, the result is

`[{'country': 'France', 'visits': 12, 'cities': ['Paris', 'Lille', 'Dijon']}, 'country', 'visits', 'cities']`.

The values in germany disappeared.

But when I use `travel_log.append(germany)`, the result is

`[{'country': 'France', 'visits': 12, 'cities': ['Paris', 'Lille', 'Dijon']}, {'country': 'Germany', 'visits': 5, 'cities': ['Berlin', 'Hamburg', 'Stuttgart']}]`

This is the correct one.

Why these two results are diffrent?

Comment: Might help to check what is the output of `print(list(germany))`

Comment: `travel_log += [germany]` should be the "right" counterpart to `append`

Comment: @Daniel Hao I did that and everything looks good to me. Could you be more precise?

Comment: @cards -  My bad - something missing here

Answer (score 3):

Because `+=` extends the list with another iterable, and iterating over a dict iterates over the keys (try `print(list(germany))`).

You'd get the same effect with `travel_log.extend(germany)`.

`.append(x)` doesn't iterate over `x`, it just appends it as-is to the list.

Answer (score 0):

The two results are different because `+=` and `.append` are designed to do completely different things.

`.append` adds a value to the end of a list. For example:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
a.append(4)
print(a)
# => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`+=` adds all the values from another iterable to the end of the list - it does the same as `.extend`. If you tried to do `a += 4` in the example above, it would error as `4` is not an iterable.

However, you are adding a dictionary, and a dictionary is an iterable - iterating over it will iterate over its keys. Hence `+=` here does not error, but instead adds all the keys of the dictionary to the list (without erroring).